# How to deploy ReactJS frontend and NodeJS/Express backend from the same project folder?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment

GitHub repo: https://github.com/byeung2019/MIQSTechnologies

Hey guys,

This is my first time deploying a website online, so I'm confused and anxious of where to even begin.

My frontend is built using ReactJS, and my backend uses NodeJS/Express/GraphQL to fetch data from an external API ([CryptoCompare](https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/)).

My website works locally.

My frontend and backend each has its own unique `package.json` and `.env` file with its respective dependencies and dev dependencies.

Through my research it's been recommended to host the frontend using Netlify, and the backend with Heroku.

However, since this is my first time deploying, I'm confused about the following:

1. How to deploy the frontend and backend **separately** from the *same* project folder, with them having their own respective `package.json` file.
2. Would I need to rewrite code in `index.js` within the `backend` folder in order to connect my `frontend` GraphQL requests to my backend.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is a complicated question to provide an exact answer, you will have to google and learn few things. But here is a high level idea.

After developing any app using react or angularjs you can follow the build instructions and build the app. It is `ng build --prod` in angular for example. Then you just need the build to deploy and it does not depend on `package.json`

You have to deploy your backend app as it is and there is few options then you can follow most common is,

- Using a proxy like nginx
- Host your build inside the node backend

Here is a guide how to host your apps using nginx for nodejs and angular
https://www.journaldev.com/27234/nginx-reverse-proxy-node-angular

Hope you will get the idea.

Comment: With ReactJS, I can type `npm run build` to build the app. My concern is my lack of knowledge in how to deploy the frontend separately from the backend, and somehow connect the two so that the frontend can send requests to the backend.

Comment: That's where the proxy servers like nginx, apache come in just follow the guide you will understand i guess. You have to use nginx proxy pass if you want to use nginx

Comment: I read through the guide but I am not sure if it is entirely applicable to my case.

Comment: It is depend on your requirement, there is few options and you have to select them by selecting which is suitable for your requirements

Comment: Try this article https://blog.cloudboost.io/run-your-angular-app-on-nodejs-c89f1e99ddd3

Comment: Did you find it? Please help me if you did